# PHP Unserialize from jquery serialize multiple rows

Tags: php, jquery, json, serialization

Good afternoon,

We are doing an jquery ajax call with the .serialize() function.  We are doing this because the form has multiple columns/rows that we would like to save with one call to ajax.  The serialize function takes all the pertinent form data and serializes it.  Here is what gets sent to the php ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/SaveClaimParts.php",
            data: { 
                'ClaimID': $('.hdn-claim-id').val(),
                'Parts': $('.parts-form').serialize()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log("Happy");
            },
            error: function()
            {
                console.log("An error occurred while processing the save.");
            }
        });
```

This works great because when I see what gets sent to the server to be processed looks something like this.

**claim_part_no**=12349&**claim_part_desc**=TUBE&**claim_part_no**=85555&**claim_part_desc**=BRACKET

Please note the duplicated part_no and part_desc.  This is not a mistake but rather the fact that there are 2 rows that we want to submit.  Each row contains a part # and a part desc.

The question now is how do I break this string up in php so that it can be saved/inserted row-by-row.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$Parts = $_POST['Parts'];
$PartsArray = array();
parse_str($Parts, $PartsArray);
```

This works but it only has the last row in $PartsArray.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.
George Eivaz

Comment: can I suggest renaming `claim_part_desc` to `row[0][claim_part_desc]` and `row[1][claim_part_desc]` etc so PHP can process it in a nice and easy row array, or use the `claim_part_no` as part of the key. Otherwise as long as you have no checkbox fields or empty fields you may get away with using `claim_part_desc[]` and stitching the arrays together by index.

Comment: Please show more of an attempt. Please post your intended query using the sample input data.  @Scuzzy is right, if you want an array of `claim_part_no`'s then you need to restructure your `$_POST` data to be multi-dimensional -- otherwise you'll be overwriting values.

Comment: Even though I don't have control over the html part, I did bring this up to the "web developers" and they did agree to code all future "rows" using the index no.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your provided string:

**claim_part_no=12349&claim_part_desc=TUBE&claim_part_no=85555&claim_part_desc=BRACKET**

**EDIT:** Since you have repeating keys, it makes more sense not to use an associative array for this. The following code is updated to reflect retaining your keys despite repetition in the javascript serialization.

You can parse this using `strpos` and `substr`,
something like this:

```
$current_key = 0;
foreach ( explode( '&', $str ) as $substring )
{
    $divisor = strpos( $substring, '=' );
    $key = substr( $substring, 0, $divisor );
    $val = substr( $substring, $divisor + 1, strlen( $substring ) );
    $PartsArray[$current_key][$key] = $val;
    if ( $key == 'claim_part_no' )
    {
        $current_key++;
    }
}
```

Then if you `var_dump( $partsArray );` you should get something like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'claim_part_no' => string '12349' (length=5)
      'claim_part_desc' => string 'TUBE' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'claim_part_no' => string '85555' (length=5)
      'claim_part_desc' => string 'BRACKET' (length=7)
```

This should work ok as long as your serialization does not include `&` or `=` as part of the return values, so don't use it to parse anything that is url encoded *(`&` will encode to `&amp;` and break this)*.

Comment: I just noticed that you repeat keys, hang on a sec and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for you help.  This put me in the right frame of mind to get what I needed done.